# Continuous printing while loop and return error

Tags: python, micropython

After running the code, the "Incorrect password." is printing continuously and there are error in returning and if statement in while loop.

```
import random
from machine import Pin, PWM
import time

number_1_pin = Pin(18) 
number_2_pin = Pin(19) 
number_3_pin = Pin(20)

green_led_pin = Pin(14, Pin.OUT) 
red_led_pin = Pin(12, Pin.OUT)

password = [random.randint(1, 5), random.randint(1, 5), random.randint(1, 5)]

number_1_pwm = PWM(number_1_pin)
number_1_pwm.freq(100)
number_1_pwm.duty_u16(0)

number_2_pwm = PWM(number_2_pin)
number_2_pwm.freq(100)
number_2_pwm.duty_u16(0)

number_3_pwm = PWM(number_3_pin)
number_3_pwm.freq(100)
number_3_pwm.duty_u16(0)

number_1_pwm.duty_u16(password[0], 20) 
number_2_pwm.duty_u16(password[1], 20) 
number_3_pwm.duty_u16(password[2]*20)
# Define the pin numbers for the rows and columns of the keypad
row_pins = [2, 3, 4, 5]
col_pins = [6, 7, 9]

# Create a list to store the keys
keys = ["1", "2", "3",
    "4", "5", "6",
    "7", "8", "9",
    "", "0", "#"]

# Create a function to read the keypad
def read_keypad():
    entered_password = ""
     for col in range(3):
        # Set the current column as low
        Pin(col_pins[col], Pin.OUT, value=0)
        for row in range(4):
            # Check if the current row is low
            if Pin(row_pins[row]).value() == 0:
                # Add the key at the current row and column to the entered password
                entered_password += keys[row 3 + col]
                break
        # Wait for a moment before checking the next column
        time.sleep(0.3)
    return entered_password

# Complete and create the whole loop for this code : 
while True:
    user_input = read_keypad()
    if user_input:
        if len(user_input) != 3 or not user_input.isdigit():
            print("Please enter a 3 digit number.")
        elif user_input == "".join(str(x) for x in password): 
            print("Correct password!") 
            # Turn on green LED 
            green_led_pin.value(1) 
            time.sleep(2) 
            green_led_pin.value(0) 
            break
        else: 
            print("Incorrect password.") 
            # Turn on red LED 
            red_led_pin.value(1) 
            time.sleep(2) 
            red_led_pin.value(0)
            # Clear user_input
            user_input = ""
    else:
        print("Please enter a password.")
        red_led_pin.value(1) 
        time.sleep(2) 
        red_led_pin.value(0)

number_1_pwm.deinit() 
number_2_pwm.deinit() 
number_3_pwm.deinit()`
```

Can someone help me find the solution for certain errors in my code. This is supposed to be part of my guessing game project using raspberry pi. Thank you so much!

Here's the error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzDNS.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "there are error in returning and if statement in while loop"? If you're getting a traceback can you please post it?

Comment: I have already edited the post. Thank you!

Comment: perhaps you should write a callback that runs the next part whenever the result is rdy(from the machine). i personally prefer run this program Asynchronous. however can't test it. try to check the read_keypad function with some prints inside and outside.. make sure it's running fine.actually don't have more guesses.

Comment: Consider developing and debugging the `read_keypad` function separate from the rest of the program. It's not clear what it's supposed to do - it will give some (wrong) answer when no key is pressed, it appears to give unexpected results if two keys are pressed at the same time, etc. Break down that part of the problem first and work from there.

Comment: Don't create variables which have numbers. Use a list instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.